# Link a word to a web page in the search engine on my website eg (car = car.html)

Tags: php, html, search

I would to make search for a page instead of tags... 
For example if someone types the word "car" in the search, then it will take you to the page called car.html/php

So, link a word to a url/page.. 
 Please can you help, you can use example of "car" :)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Prepends actual URL by"http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; and then put ur search string.. And then append. .HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call this function

```
window.location.href = "http://example.com/" + value + ".html";
```

and it will redirect the page to searchValue.html